# Do I have to use a new certificate to update my app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes

I'm going to update an iphone app but I cannot Testing it on the itunes portal.

I made the update in itunes portal, I build it, and When I want to validate it, it doesn't runing because of certificate so I'm asking if I don't have to make a new certificate?

When I use the certificate that I used for the first submission:

```
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or ti was signed with an Apple submission certificate.
```

The status of the certificate on the Portal is Active.

I put All the line of "Code signing" to iPhone Distribution and edit scheme>Archive>Release :
[printscreen](http://imgpaste.com/9dGr.png).

I re-sign the app with the same certificate when I try to validate it on iTunes...

Thanks to help me

**EDIT : I make that but I still have the same problem:**

[Download certificate](http://imgpaste.com/g71i.png)
[Import it and deletete old one](http://imgpaste.com/IB75.png)
[set the new certificate overall ^^](http://imgpaste.com/6QgJ.png)
[Get the error xD](http://imgpaste.com/HZDq.png)

Please help me I need to do that before monday

Comment: Are you getting any error messages you could quote in your question?

Comment: yes may be it is expired... in that case just renew and re-download the certificate from provisioning portal

Comment: Joachim : Ok thanks I've updated the first post ;-) @yasir : Apparently, the certificate is Active. There will be no problem if I download the new certificate and delete which I have at the moment? it's well this one : imgpaste.com/JjrW.png ? Thanks

Comment: @yasim : I download the certificate again, I deleted the old, I put the new one, I restarted XCode, I build the app and finally, I have the same error. please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed indications to make Ad-Hoc on the official portal : http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action. It says that we have to make a new entry on entitlements (get-task-allow at true) and I didn't delete the row in the entitlements file!!

Now all sounds OK, sumbitted !

Comment: If you're using Xcode 4, you can just delete your entitlements file (make sure to remove the references to it in your build settings) and it will automatically do everything - at least that works for me! Glad you got it fixed, anyway.

Comment: OK I followed that tuto and I replace thr old entitlements to the new created for ad hoc provisioning... crazy ! Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

If your old certificate has expired you need to create a new one to be able to update your app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the certificate on the computer that generated it in the first place? If not, your public key doesn't match and you'll have to request a new one even if the current one hasn't expired.

Comment: Thanks for your attention / answer. Yes i Do :-/

Comment: then is it a production cert instead of being a development one?

Comment: I re-download and implement the certificat from the portal but I have the same error

Comment: when you do the Archive, are you selecting the Distribution certificate again? sometimes I skip over that part and it auto-selects the dev one again.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. yes, I select the same certificate (distribution).

Can I check the validity of all the certificate separately?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your code signing build settings are automatically detecting which certificate/profile to use. The image is cut off so I can't see what certificate/profile combo is being used, but it sounds as if it is selecting your Ad-Hoc combo and not your App Store combo. Try changing the code signing build settings for the target(s) you are using to build for the App Store manually to your App Store profile. If this makes no difference, can you please show the rest of your code signing settings (not chopped off on the right)?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. In fact I put all on the same certificate to be sure that it's signed with that certificate (the menu shows wich certificate is used : imgpaste.com/REv9.png ) and here is the scheme used : imgpaste.com/UU6F.png

Comment: And if you go into the Organizer, choose Provisioning Profiles and select the profile you are using, what do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your ask. error is "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate" - imgpaste.com/L99s.png . I use the same user certificate (in my keychain) than before, I didn't edit/add/delete it

Comment: You misunderstood me. Could you go into the organiser and find your provisioning profile so I can see its properties?

Comment: @jrct27 : THANKS. First : I took some screens of my certificates lists on keychain, there could be trouble with one certificate (I made lot of sh** with tests on a iPone to debug it) : imgpaste.com/PqtT.png - imgpaste.com/ABD3.png - imgpaste.com/LbrH.png . About the Organizer, I sign again with the same certificate : imgpaste.com/VbXP.png

Comment: Still not quite it. What do you get if you go to here? http://i.imgur.com/LzubZ.png Does it say that the profile cannot be installed on devices, or does it just list the devices?

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. "cannot be installed on devices" : imgpaste.com/iPAp.png . and There is something trouble woth that picture : imgpaste.com/aGor.png isn't it ?

Comment: and there is no trouble with all those certificates : imgpaste.com/zk9D.png ?

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6926/discussion-between-jrtc27-and-clement)